# JSON to Firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to both firebase and JSON, and I'm having a weird issue where it starts the firebase database with a zero.
JSON:

```
[{
"Location" : {
    "0" : {
        "name" : "Huntington Beach",
        "address" : "602 Pacific Coast Hwy, Huntington Beach, CA 92648",
        "hours" : "Sun 8am-8pm, Mon - Sat 8am-9pm",
        "phoneNumber" : "(714) 536-TACO(8226)"
    },
    "1" : {
        "name" : "Newport Beach",
        "address" : "3014 W Balboa Blvd, Newport Beach, CA 92663",
        "hours" : "Sun 8am-8pm, Mon - Sat 8am-9pm",
        "phoneNumber" : "(949) 723-TACO(8226)"
    }
}
}]
```

[Firebase After Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDamk.png)

Comment: That's because you are importing an array. Try removing the surrounding `[]` - then you will have `Location` at the root.

Comment: Using arrays with Firebase is typically an anti-pattern. Read this blog post to learn more: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your problem is the squared brackets `[]`.

```
[{ // <--------- THIS [
"Location" : {
    "0" : {
        "name" : "Huntington Beach",
        "address" : "602 Pacific Coast Hwy, Huntington Beach, CA 92648",
        "hours" : "Sun 8am-8pm, Mon - Sat 8am-9pm",
        "phoneNumber" : "(714) 536-TACO(8226)"
    },
    "1" : {
        "name" : "Newport Beach",
        "address" : "3014 W Balboa Blvd, Newport Beach, CA 92663",
        "hours" : "Sun 8am-8pm, Mon - Sat 8am-9pm",
        "phoneNumber" : "(949) 723-TACO(8226)"
    }
}
}] // <--------- THIS ]
```

Those brackets indicate that you're saving an `Array`. An array is a `container` of `objects`. And even tho you only got one object in your container, your Firebase sets a number for it, because it does not know upfront the number of objects. And 0 because in informatics `0 = 1`

Delete the `[]` or (as I know from your other question, that you are a Swift Developer), take the object out of your Array. Like:

```
let yourArray: [JSON] = []
for element in yourArray {
    yourUploadFunc(element)
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the issue, now it's onto diving into firebase